# Can't see which friends liked a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I manage two Facebook pages, and I have the following problem: on one, if someone goes to the page they can see who of their friends liked it, while it is not the case with the other. I cannot seem to find a setting for this in the page settings.

I attached two photos, when viewing the page as a visitor.
First (this works fine):

[image: first page, showing friends who liked the page]

Second (this doesn't work):

[image: second page, with no list of friends]

In the first picture, I can see how many my friends like the page and who they are, and this is not the case in the second. (I know for a fact that I have at least 100 friends who like the other page.)

Where can I control this?